# shell command with Ansible playbook doesn't work

Tags: linux, ansible, umask

I have added to my playbook a small task that should change umask on my linux machine:

```
  - name: set umask to 0022
    shell: umask 0022
```

When running the playbook, I can see this task passes successfully:

```
changed: [myHostName] => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": "umask 0022",
"delta": "0:00:00.004660",
"end": "2020-08-04 16:28:44.153261",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "umask 0022",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "stdin_add_newline": true,
        "strip_empty_ends": true,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"rc": 0,
"start": "2020-08-04 16:28:44.148601",
"stderr": "",
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
}
```

but After the playbook finishes, I check the umask and see that it was not changed at all:

```
-bash-4.2$ umask
0044
```

I also put a debug in my playbook right after the task I showed above, and the debug also shows that the umask was not changed..
Tried also with

```
become: yes
```

But got the same result..

When I do the command on my Linux manually, it will work:

```
-bash-4.2$ umask 0022
-bash-4.2$ umask
0022
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *After the playbook finishes, I check the umask and see that it was not changed at all.*

A: This is correct. [Ansible isn't really doing things through the shell](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4974#issuecomment-28915252) i.e. the changes live in this one session only.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know the changes live in the session only. That's why I mentioned that right after the task I added a debug that shows the umask. So when the playbook arrives at this debug, I should see umask is 0022 right? But I see umask 0044 i.e didn't change.

Comment: What this means is that the umask only changes for that session. Try `shell: umask 0022 && umask`. Then debug the `stdout`. To "set" the umask, it would be better to use `/etc/profile` (system-wide) or `~/.bashrc` (user-specific)